# Returning values from multiprocessing function

Tags: python, process, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I am facing a problem while using multiprocessing module in python. My aim is to create m*n processes ( where m*n are the dimensions of an image) and change all the values of the pixel (In the below code, change value from 0 to 255).
Inside the function, I can see the values of pixel changing with the help of print function. But when I am displaying the output image at the end, there is no change in the image contents. Can someone let me know where is the problem ?

```
import cv2
import numpy
import multiprocessing

def func(i,j,img_op):
    #print("For pixel",i,j)
    img_op[i][j]=255
    print("For pixel", i, j,"\t",img_op[i][j])
    return img_op[i][j]

img=cv2.imread('pokemon.png',0)
height = numpy.size(img, 0)
width = numpy.size(img, 1)
img_op=numpy.zeros((height,width,1),numpy.uint8)

print(height,width)

processes=[]
for i in range(0,height-2):
    for j in range(0,width-2):
        p=multiprocessing.Process(target=func,args=(i,j,img_op,))
        processes.append(p)
        p.start()

for p in processes:
    p.join()

cv2.imshow('Original image',img)
cv2.imshow('White IMage',img_op)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Did my answer help you?

Answer (score 0):

*This actually is a tricky problem, that deals with low-level system primitives, such as `fork` and `mmap`*

The problem is that the processes do not share memory.
As a result, each process is working on its own copy of the initial array.
This is a consequence of the way processes are created, through the `fork` system call: the current process, code and memory, is copied as a new process, and they both continue their respective execution.

There are a lot of workarounds, but the most straightforward would be using a memory mapping.
A memory mapping is an object created by the `mmap` system call, that maps a section of the disk into RAM and is accessible as a file descriptor.
Since file descriptors are actually not copied on a `fork`, those will in effect be shared across processes.

Fortunately, numpy defines an abstraction of the traditional `mmap` object that has an array interface: `np.memmap`.
As I said, a memory mapping is backed by a file on disk, so you need to provide it with a path, and a, access mode.

You could define your global image as follows:

```
img_op = np.memmap(
    "/tmp/shared_image", dtype=np.uint8, mode='w+', shape=(height, width, 1)
)
```

Since the `np.memmap` object has an array interface, it can be used anywhere and the same way a regular array can be used.